# Making coulmns in MySQL conditionally NULL

Tags: mysql

Hi I'm new to MySQL and database specifically. Following is my code:

```
UPDATE lab.labdata1 SET Date='$d1', Month='$m1', Year='$y1', Time='$n1', Used='$n11' WHERE SL=1
```

I want to make updated columns NULL after 48 hours since its been last updated. Is it possible, if so kindly help me. (FYI : I'm using this inside PHP code)

Comment: like your going to run this query from php to make fields null or do you want it to be a procedure where the database sets it to null after 48 hours?

Comment: This looks [terrifyingly insecure](http://bobby-tables.com/). Are you **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php)?

Comment: Why aren't you using MySQL's `DATE` or `DATETIME` column type? Doing it this way is obnoxiously difficult to work with.

Comment: Thanks guys for replying. @boomoto: Anything is fine either through PHP code or writing a procedure in database.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using datetime field, here is an example code if you were to update your table:

```
UPDATE lab.labdata1 set Used= null, lastupdated = NOW() where lastupdated < (NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY)
```

Comment: Thank you boomoto, I will try this and let you know the result.

Comment: I'm getting the following error : #1054 - Unknown column 'lastupdated' in 'where clause'

Comment: Did you redesign your table? lastupdated would be a column in your table.

Comment: I don't have a 'lastupdated' column in my table. The system column to show the updated time is update_time but it is showing null all the time. There is a bug in this mysql database (phpmyadmin)

Comment: FOund the solution finally: I used the below code: UPDATE labdata1 SET Date = NULL WHERE updated_at < (NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MINUTE) . I created a column called updated_at since there was a problem with the system column Update_time.